# Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed that is not supported

Tags: python, django, virtualbox, vagrant

I am working my way through http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/introduction-and-launch/

I am working on win7 and using git-bash for my terminal. I have gotten to :

```
Shared Folders
After the ./postinstall.sh step, exit SSH Run vagrant halt.
```

I tried to run vagrant halt and got:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ vagrant halt 
Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed that is not supported. Please install one of the supported versions listed below to use Vagrant:

4.0, 4.1
```

I have installed the latest virtualbox - 4.2.12

what do I do now?

Comment: You have an old version of vagrant. Just uninstall the current one, and install the latest one. http://downloads.vagrantup.com/tags/v1.2.2

Comment: if you write this as an answer I can upvote it

Comment: My solution was forgetting about vagrant and setting up the environment elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an old version of vagrant. Just uninstall the current one, and install the latest one.

https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/

Comment: The link seems out of date.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading Vagrant isn't the only answer to this problem. I have hit it a few times after installing a new kernel. The issue in my case was that VirtualBox didn't automatically rebuild its modules.

My solution was to purge & re-install the `virtualbox-dkms` package, e.g.:

```
brendan@ishmael:~$ sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms
brendan@ishmael:~$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

This triggered building the modules for my current kernel. After this, even my older version of Vagrant sees the correct version of VirtualBox.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms
realpath: G/bin/win-sudo/s/sudobackend: No such file or directory